# S3 website downloads files instead of displaying pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to setup a static page on S3 with Terraform. When I access the endpoint my browser tries to download the file instead of displaying the page.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b1" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "error.html"
  }
  tags = {
    Name        = "my bucket"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.b1.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.b1.id
  key    = "index.html"
  source = "myfiles/index.html"
  etag   = filemd5("myfiles/index.html")
}
```

Comment: You could try adding / specifying `content_type` to the `aws_s3_bucket_object`.

Answer (score 4):

By default, S3 objects have the generic content type `application/octet-stream`, which browsers typically handle by just downloading the file because there isn't enough information to choose a more specific handling.

You can set a different content type using the `content_type` argument to `aws_s3_bucket_object`. The expected content type for an HTML file is `text/html`, so you can configure your object like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object" {
  bucket       = aws_s3_bucket.b1.id
  key          = "index.html"
  source       = "myfiles/index.html"
  etag         = filemd5("myfiles/index.html")
  content_type = "text/html"
}
```

If you have a variety of objects with different types to upload, you might find it easier to use [the shared module `hashicorp/dir/template`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/dir/template/latest), which includes in its implementation a default mapping table from filename suffixes to appropriate `content_type` values, and so you can potentially process a directory of files which have conventional filename suffixes and then [map the result systematically into S3 objects](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/dir/template/latest#uploading-files-to-amazon-s3).